# ¿Necesito crear una grilla con numeros random a partir de un bucle while?

Tags: php, while, condiciones

Necesito crear una grilla de 8 elementos con el nombre de los artículos, la cantidad y el precio con números aleatorios, llevo esto hecho pero no se como hacer para formar la grilla.

```
<?php

$i = 0;

while ($i == 8) {
$i = rand(1,100);
echo $i."<br>;
$i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Hola Sora Kasugano, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que quieres algo como esto:

```
   <table>
   <tr><td>Nombre</td><td>Cantidad</td><td>Precio</td></tr>

   <?php
   $i = 1;
   while ($i <= 8) { echo $i++
        echo "<tr>
                 <td>Nombre".$a."</td>
                 <td>50</td>
                 <td>".(rand(1,100))."</td>
              </tr>";
    }
    ?>

    </table>
```

Comment: si pero tiene que ser si o so con un ciclo while por eso no me sale

Comment: Te he actualizado la respuesta con un while :)